# Passing cython argument as reference with Unknown type

Tags: python, cython

I am creating c++ wrapper to python code using Cython.
The cdef function is as follows

```
import cv2

cdef public void Load_Cascades(object& face_cascade, object& eye_cascade):
  face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
  eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
  print("Cascades loaded!!")
```

the type of the arguments are unknown and so I have used `object` and `&` is to pass them as reference variables. The calling function is as follows

```
cdef public void Run():
  face_cascade = None;
  eye_cascade = None;
  Load_Cascades(face_cascade, eye_cascade)
```

With such a code, there is error from the cython compiler that the reference variables cannot be changed.

I also called the function by passing address

```
Load_Cascades(&face_cascade, &eye_cascade)
```

This does not work as well, Can you please let me know how can I achieve the passing of unknown type variables via reference in cython

Comment: You don't. `object` basically says "treat this as Python" and Python doesn't work like that. You return the variables you want to change.

Comment: [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/nXsytgkTbGg) is possibly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `object` makes the argument a default Python argument, the mutability of Python is taken into consideration. Thus I merged all the arguments into a `list` which is mutable by default, it worked!

So the code is now

```
import cv2
cdef public void Load_Cascades(cascade):
  cascade.append(cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'))
  cascade.append(cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml'))
  print("Cascades loaded!!")
```

While calling the function, I just pass an empty list

```
cdef public void Run():
  cascade = []
  Load_Cascades(cascade)
```

Thank you David for the input